# React avoid rerender of parent component when changing state from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState({});

  return <Child setA={setA} />
}

const Child = ({ setA }) => {
  const [b, setB] = useState();
  const handleSomething = () => {
    setB({});
    setA({});
  }

  return b.map(etc => (...));
}
```

Basically, I want to avoid rerendering Parent component when `a` changes. Because this makes `Child` rerenders and it resets the internal state. How can I avoid it?

Comment: You're modifying the parent in the child. setA directly changes the parent state. If you're modifying the props of the parent, the parent is going to render.

Comment: ^-- yeah, you seem to be asking how to avoid rerendering the Parent to stop the Child from rerendering. Do you instead want to just avoid the child from rerendering? The parent needs to rerender when its state changes, the child doesn't.

Comment: @JoelHager yes but I don't use `a` for anything visual, just to send it in a handler in the `Parent`, so how can I avoid rerendering `Parent` even if A changes?

Comment: If `a` changes the parent will rerender, but that won't reset the state of Child unless you're doing something else to do so (or setting it from props?)

Comment: @pilchard thanks, yeah it was another thing, I just left an answer for if someone has the same or similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was wrong, the rerender wasn't triggered because of the `a` or `setA`, it was because I was passing an object to Child like this

```
<Child filters={{someFilter, someOtherFilter}} setA={setA} />
```

To fix this I did this:

```
const filters = useMemo(() => ({ someFilter, someOtherFilter }), [someFilter, someOtherFilter])

<Child filters={filters} setA={setA} />
```

Comment: The reason useMemo is doing it is because it's checking the value and pausing the rerender. That's what I was going to suggest. However, if you affect state/props in the parent, it's going to render by default.